# Q: Volume involving spherical and polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

I'm trying to find the volume between the surfaces defined by the following equations:
$$
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = b^2
$$
$$
y^2 \tan^2 a = x^2 + z^2
$$
I need to find the volume using two different methods: the first one is by spherical coordinates and the second one by polar coordinates. The problem is I get two different results:

Using spherical coordinates I found:
$$
x = \rho \sin \phi \cos \theta \\
z = \rho \sin \phi \sin \theta \\
y = \rho \cos \phi
$$
$$
V= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{a}\int_0^{b}\rho^2\sin\phi \:d\rho d\phi d\theta = \frac{2\pi}{3}b^3(-\cos(a)+1)
$$
and using polar:
$$
x = r \cos \theta \\
z = r \sin \theta \\
y = y
$$
$$
V = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{b\sin a}\int_0^{\sqrt{b^2-r^2}}r \:dy dr d\theta = -\frac{2\pi}{3}b^3(\cos^3(a)-1)
$$
So I know I have made a mistake at some point but I can't find it. If anyone can help I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Really good work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your working for spherical coordinates is correct. In cylindrical coordinates, the lower bound of $y$ is incorrect. Rest everything is correct.

The lower bound of $y$ as zero for all values of $r$ will mean you are integrating over a cylinder. Please note that $y$ is bound below by the surface of the cone and hence,

$y^2 \tan^2 a = r^2 \implies y = r \cot a$.

So the integral should be,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{b\sin a}\int_{ \color {blue} {r \cot a}}^{\sqrt{b^2-r^2}} r \ dy \ dr \ d\theta$